Delete record which does not exists
I want to delete records which does not exists from one table with another. For eg:
Products:



ID
Category
ProductName




1
C1
P1


2
C2,C1
P2


3
C3,C1
P3


4
C2,C1
P4


5
C5
P5



Categories:



ID
Name




1
C1


2
C2


3
C3


4
C4


5
C5


6
C6


7
C7


8
C8



Now my requirement is that i want to delete the invalid/records that does not exists in products table from categories table.
For eg: I want a query which will delete records from Categories table like: C6, C7 and C8 as these categories does not exists inside products table.
Can anyone please help me on this issue, it will be appreciated.

We don't post images of sample data here. It makes it less likely you'll get an answer, because now we have to retype the data into fiddle to setup a test, and ain't no one got time for that.

You'll want to use STRING_SPLIT() to split Table_Products.Category into rows. Then it's just a matter of doing a DELETE FROM Table_Categories WHERE Name NOT IN (<your string_split select statement>); type of DELETE statement.

Thank you @JoelCoehoorn, but how can we add/show table data then?

Thank You @JNevill, let me try with String_Split()

I fixed the first one for you. You should do the same for the other. Also: putting CSV or other structured data in a single column is pretty much always the wrong thing to do when designing a schema. If you can change the table design to add a table mapping products to categories, or giving each category a separate column, that will be a big win.

Ok sure thank you so much @JoelCoehoorn. I will take care of this from next time

@JNevill can you please create a query for this using String_Split() if possible

Are you sure you want to do this? Even though categories don't have products right now, maybe they will later?

@siggemannen, there won't be any products later on as well. I want to delete these invalid category data because all categories are listing in menu control which makes it more scrollable unnecessary.

@RahulParab I guess JNevill meant something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/TixksfxR?hide=8. It's similar to this answer, but with NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS. I would prefer NOT IN here, but that's just kind of taste, both will work fine.

@RahulParab we need your SQL-Server version in order to recommend the best or most modern solution for you. run select @@version;

@testing-for-ya I know about this possible issue, that's why I wrote "I would prefer it here", not "I would always prefer it". I think it depends on the use case. If you're sure the column will never be nullable, I think NOT IN is simpler to read. But as already said, kind of taste. I commented/answered on other questions with other use cases the other way and reommended NOT EXISTS ;)

@testing-for-ya In my opinion, this site's purpose is not to be a tutorial or generally to help people learn SQL. SO's purpose is to help people solving a specific issue. And NOT IN is an absolute fine pattern for many queries fetching data from non nullable columns. I also think comments are not made for opinionated discussions, so this will be my last comment on this topic.

Using lessons from Joining against a CSV Column in SQL Server
This query will help you find all of the Category names that exists or not within the Table_Products category column.
SELECT * 
FROM Table_Categories C
LEFT JOIN Table_Products P ON CHARINDEX(',' + C.Name + ',', ',' + P.Category +',') > 0

The delete statement would be:
DELETE C 
FROM Table_Categories  C
LEFT JOIN Table_Products P ON CHARINDEX(',' + C.Name + ',', ',' + P.Category +',') > 0
WHERE P.ID IS NULL

fiddle

Thank you @Bart McEndree, let me try with this query

Might work as expected, but I think this CHARINDEX idea is quite obsolete and bad to read. STRING_SPLIT is much simpler.

@Jonas Metzler  STRING_SPLIT is only available starting with SQL Server 2016

In other words: Since 8 years, we should use it. As we also use JOIN today rather than comma-"joining" tables.
